# beforeunload doesn't work when binding to event listener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, onbeforeunload

need help with beforeunload event. I was trying to add a event listener for 'beforeunload' to my page like this `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', log.Flush());` and it doesn't go through the `flush()` function when I click on a link to navigate away from the page.

Although, when I set the

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                return log.Flush();
            };
```

debugger goes through the `Flush()` function. Any hint why? Is there a better standard way to set a function to be called when `beforeunload`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are executing the function directly and hence passing its return value as the event handler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're invoking your function in place of subscription, instead of this try to just reference to your function.

`window.addEventListener('beforeunload', log.Flush);`